# Quasi Random Number generation Scatter plot

Tags: python, random, cython

```
Require python code for Quasi random number generation scatter plot. Tried this method but getting name not found error as shown below 
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg5og.png)             
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a6o8.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2O04.png)
I tries to obtain quasi random number generator scatter plot. But got name not found error as shown below. I used Jupiter notebook

I tried calling the function inside the main code still it's not displaying the output scatter plots.

<!-- begin snippet:  hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
# Connecting cython one cell in jupiter notebook
        %load_ext Cython
        # another cell
        %%cython
        import gsl
        from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Free
    
        # Declare the few types and functions we need
        cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_qrng.h":
            ctypedef struct gsl_qrng
            # Declare the few types and functions we need
            ctypedef struct gsl_qrng_type
            gsl_qrng_type* gsl_qrng_sobol
            # Declare the few types and functions we need
            gsl_qrng* gsl_qrng_alloc(gsl_qrng_type* T, unsigned int d)
            void gsl_qrng_free(gsl_qrng* q)
            # Declare the few types and functions we need
            int gsl_qrng_get(const gsl_qrng * q, double x[])
    
        # This is the wrapper class
        cdef class Sobol:
            cdef gsl_qrng* _q
            cdef unsigned _D
            cdef double *_v
            def __cinit__(self, D=1):
                """Create a `D` dimensional Sobol sequence."""
                self._D = D
                # Declare the few types and functions we need
                # gsl_qrng_get() returns the next
                # value in one of its arguments
                self._v = <double *>PyMem_Malloc(D * sizeof(double))
                if not self._v:
                    raise MemoryError()
                
                # Actually allocate the QRNG generator
                self._q = gsl_qrng_alloc(gsl_qrng_sobol, D)
                if self._q is NULL:
                    raise MemoryError()
               # getting values 
            def get(self, int N=1):
                """The next `N` points in the sequence."""
                points = []
                for n in xrange(N):
                    points.append(self.__next__())
                    
                return points
                # getting next values
            def __next__(self):
                """Iterate over the sequence."""
                gsl_qrng_get(self._q, self._v)
                return [self._v[i] for i in xrange(self._D)]
            
            def __iter__(self):
                return self
            
            # Make sure we free all the memory we allocated
            def __dealloc__(self):
                if self._q is not NULL:
                    gsl_qrng_free(self._q)
                    
                PyMem_Free(self._v)
        # another cell 
        s2 = Sobol(2)
        # Declare the few types and functions we need
        sobol_X, sobol_Y = zip(*s2.get(100))
        # Declare the few types and functions we need
        sobol_X2 = (np.array(sobol_X) + np.random.uniform())%1
        sobol_Y2 = (np.array(sobol_Y) + np.random.uniform())%1
    
        X = np.random.uniform(size=(100*2))
        # Declare the few types and functions we need
        f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12,4))
        ax1.scatter(X[:100], X[100:],)
        ax2.scatter(sobol_X, sobol_Y, color="red")
        ax3.scatter(sobol_X2, sobol_Y2, color="green")
    
        ax1.set_title("Random")
        ax2.set_title("quasi")
        ax3.set_title("quasi again")
```

```js
Error:
    
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19752\3909363266.py in <module>
        ----> 1 s2 = Sobol(2)
              2 
              3 sobol_X, sobol_Y = zip(*s2.get(100))
              4 
              5 sobol_X2 = (np. array(sobol_X) + np. random. uniform())%1
    
        Name Error: name 'Sobol' is not defined
```

Here I have used 3 cells to perform operations. One cell is to connect Cython. One cell is for cython logic and other cell is for python code were we call cython function.

Can i know what is the error. Also do we need to import Gsl or is there any other way to find a scatter plot for quasi random number generation?

Comment: Images of code/errors are not acceptable. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: why are you using GSL? e.g. the standard SciPy library includes a Sobol sequence generator which would presumably make things much easier

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any examples on this site of plotting the output of Scipy's [Quasi Monte-Carlo generators](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.qmc.html), so here's one that replicates the first plot of Wikipedia's entry on the [Sobol sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence):

```
# import generators from SciPy
from scipy.stats import qmc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create 2D Sobol sequence and draw 256 points
qr = qmc.Sobol(2, scramble=False)
XY = qr.random(256)

# plot points
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(
    XY[:,0], XY[:,1],
    facecolor='none',
    edgecolor=['C1'] * 10 + ['C0'] * 90 + ['C2'] * 154,
    linewidth=2,
)
ax.margins(0.02)
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

which produces:

[image: matplotlib scatter plot of Sobol sequence]